# C - linked list removing values on insertion

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, insert

I'm trying to create a method that lets me insert a new node in my liked list at a chosen index,
it is currently working as intended when inserting into index 0 or 1 but when I try to insert into any index >= 2 the first value in the list is being lost. any ideas why?

example main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"


int main( void ) {
  List list = new_list();
  
  add(list, "Three");
  add(list, "Two");
  add(list, "Zero");

  print_list(list);

  printf("Inserting at 1 \n");
  insert_at(list, 1, "one")
  print_list(list);
  printf("Inserting at 2 \n");
  insert_at(list, 2, "inserted")
  print_list(list);
```

header file:

```
typedef struct Node{
    char *value;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;
typedef Node** List;
List new_list();
Node *new_node(char *value);
void add(List list,char *value);
int is_empty(List list);
void print_list(const List list);
int insert_at(List list,int index,char *value);
```

method file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"
#include <string.h>


List new_list(){
    List list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    *list = NULL;
    return list;
}

Node *new_node(char *value){
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void add(List list,char *value){
if (*list == NULL){
    *list = new_node(value);
}else {
    Node *node = new_node(value);
    node->next = *list;
    *list = node;
}
}

int is_empty(List list){
if (*list == NULL){
    return 1;
}   return 0;
}

void print_list(const List list){ 
    printf("[");
    Node *curr = *list;
if (curr == NULL){
    printf("]\n");
    return;
} 
    while (curr->next != NULL){
        printf("\"%s\", ", curr->value );
        
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    printf("\"%s\"", curr->value );
    printf("]\n");
}



int insert_at(List list,int index,char *value){
 
if ((index > 0 && is_empty(list) == 1) || index < 0){
    return 0;
}
    int i= 0;
 if (index == 0){
    add(list, value);
    return 1;
}
  
while((*list) != NULL){
    //advancing loop
    i++; 
//checking if wanted index = lists index
if (i == index){
    //creating new node
    Node *node = new_node(value);
    //updating next values;
    node->next = (*list)->next;
    (*list)->next = node;
    
    return 1;
}
  (*list) =(*list)->next;
}
  return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
["Zero", "Two", "Three"]
Inserting at 1
["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three"]
Inserting at 2
["One", "INSERTED", "Two", "Three"]
```

Comment: I suggest you start over. Not with a new program but with some pieces of paper and a pencil. Draw out all functionality using the pencil and the paper, draw small (labeled) boxes for the nodes of the list, and arrows for links and other pointers. Erase and redraw the arrows as you modify them and the list nodes. Once you have gotten something that seems to work on paper, then you start with the code to implement it. And do it only one small piece at a time, that can be easily tested and debugged.

Comment: If, during implementation, you find a problem during testing you need to *debug* your code. Use a *debugger* to step though the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Again use pencil and paper to follow along as you modify the list and the nodes, and make sure the drawings make sense and follow your earlier drawings and algorithms as you created them before. This way it will be very easy to see when and where something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this while loop

```
while((*list) != NULL){
    //advancing loop
    i++; 
//checking if wanted index = lists index
if (i == index){
    //creating new node
    Node *node = new_node(value);
    //updating next values;
    node->next = (*list)->next;
    (*list)->next = node;
    
    return 1;
}
  (*list) =(*list)->next;
}
```

the statement

```
  (*list) =(*list)->next;
```

overwrites the pointer to the head node that results at least in numerous memory leaks.

And the second function parameter should have an unsigned integer type as for example `size_t`.

Also the function `new_list` should look at least like

```
List new_list(){
    List list = malloc(sizeof( *list ));
    *list = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

In general it is a bad approach with using such a typedef

```
typedef Node** List;
```

It only confuses readers of the code.

Comment: Ok thanks I have applied your suggestions and fixed the while Loop so it no longer overwrites the head, and its all working now thanks.